# Floating menu bar in xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have seen [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_MC4zPKZTY) video on how to make a FAB menu in Xamarin.Android:

What I am looking for is, if there a way to make a floating menu (doesn't have to be as fancy as FAB) in Xamarin.Forms (solution for **cross platform**!)

If there is no cross-platform solution that is fine, I just want to be absolutely sure before I proceed.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a good implementation of it for Xamarin.Forms. It is made by great community contributor **[Alex Dunn](https://twitter.com/Suave_Pirate/)**.

You can find more about it [here](https://alexdunn.org/tag/floating-action-button/), also it is open source so you can see the code and sample on GitHub [here](https://github.com/SuavePirate/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.FloatingActionButton/tree/master/Example/SuaveControls.FabExample).

Wishing you lots of luck with coding!

Comment: Wow I'm so amazed by this solution. Thank you! I really thought nothing would exist. Any chance this solution will work for UWP also? I'm gonna try it for UWP also haha.

Comment: You can try this also: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/267968#Comment_267968